# Android set an Accessibility Focus listener

Tags: java, android, focus, accessibility, listener

What I want is to have a listener when a certain element (like a button, an image, a view or anything else) became accessibility focused. I found stuff like `mybutton.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)` but then I don't know what to do next, how to handle it. 
My main purpose is to make a sound when an element became focused instead of reading his accessibility name. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: why would you want to make a sound instead of reading it's accessibility name? I can't understand the use case for that, is it a game or something? If you want to play a sound instead of the accessible name, don't add the accessible name in the first place?

Comment: I have to make a grammatical exercise for visually impared child in which i have some cards with animals and I have to reproduce the sound of the animal when it become focused. Ok not to add the accessible name in the first place but than how to reproduce a sound when the element became focused?

Answer (score 0):

Im not much of an Android developer, but i think the event you are using is sending information to the screen reader. You would need the opposite of that.

I think the answer to this question could help you
[Google talkback API to get current focus item in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855093/google-talkback-api-to-get-current-focus-item-in-android)

Best of luck, sounds like a cool app for visually impaired children